# How can I create a normal distributed set of data in R?

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

I'm a newbie in statistics and I'm studying R.
I decided to do this exercise to pratice some analysis with an original dataset.

This is the issue: I want to create a datset of let's say 100 subjects and for each one of them I have a  test score.
This test score has a range that goes from 0 to 70 and the mean score is 48 (and its improbable that someone scores 0).

Firstly I tried to create the set with `x <- round(runif(100, min=0, max=70))` , but then I found out that were not normally distributed using plot(x).
So I searched another Rcommand and found this, but I couldn't decide the min\max:

```
ex1 <- round(rnorm(100, mean=48 , sd=5))
```

I really can't understand what I have to do!

I would like to write a function that gives me a set of data normally distributed, in a range of 0-70, with a mean of 48 and a not so big standard deviation in order to do some T-test later...
Any help?

Thanks a lot in advance guys

Comment: If you need there to be a min and max of a Normal distribution, perhaps you should research a *truncated*-Normal? I think you should understand the concept behind it before arbitrarily using it, but if you think it is the right way to go, look at the [`truncnorm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/truncnorm/) package.

Comment: (And for the record, many claims of "Normality" are a little bit of a stretch: if human height, for example, were Normally distributed, that would suggest that some would have a *negative* height. We still use "Normally distributed" in most of statistics, but very few things are truly so.)

Comment: I'll try to write it differently. If I draw a gaussian and start to add the values, for example: I have 100 subjects, 10 did 48 points, the most frequent score, then 9 did 45 and other 9 did 52 and so on until I get 1 subject that did a low score and 1 that get a high score Wouldn't be right?

Comment: I think you're missing my point about the math in general. One way to ensure that `rnorm(.)` is always within two bounds is to use something like `pmax(0, pmin(70, rnorm(100, mean=38, sd=5)))`. **However**, you will have a higher-than-normal (non-monotonic) up-ticks at the two extremes. As a much-more-constrained example, try `hist(pmax(28, pmin(48, rnorm(10000, mean=38, sd=5))))` and see the two extremes. *Not "Normal"*. I'm not talking *practical* considerations, I'm talking *technical* thoughts.

Comment: ok so it's an impossible task..keeping it simple and doing a normal distribution with that kind of data. Seeing that histogram I understand that these are not "normal" at all

Comment: It's not an impossible task using `truncnorm`. (And frankly, many may argue that the `10e-14` likelihood of `x<1` is good enough to accept, shrug their shoulders, and use `pmax`/`pmin`.)

Answer (score 4):

The normal distribution, by definition, does not have a min or max. If you go more than a few standard deviations from the mean, the probability density is very small, but not 0. You can truncate a normal distribution, chopping of the tails. Here, I use `pmin` and `pmax` to set any values below 0 to 0, and any values above 70 to 70:

```
ex1 <- round(rnorm(100, mean=48 , sd=5))   
ex1 <- pmin(ex1, 70)
ex1 <- pmax(ex1, 0)
```

You can calculate the probability of an individual observation being below or above a certain point using `pnorm`. For your mean of 48 and SD of 5, the probability an individual observation is less than 0 is **very** small:

```
pnorm(0, mean = 48, sd = 5)
# [1] 3.997221e-22
```

This probability is so small that the truncation step is unnecessary in most applications. But if you started experimenting with bigger standard deviations, or mean values closer to the bounds, it could become necessary.

This method of truncation is simple, but it is a bit of a hack. If you truncated a distribution to be within 1 SD of the mean using this method, you would end up with spikes a the upper and lower bound that are even higher than the density at the mean! But it should work well enough for less extreme applications. A more robust method might be to draw more samples than you need, and keep the first `n` samples that fall within your bounds. If you really care to do things right, there are packages that implement truncated normal distributions.

(Because the normal distribution is symmetric, and 100 is farther from your mean than 0, the probability of observations > 100 are even smaller.)

Comment: To be honest I didn't quite get it all from your explanation...only that what I was trying to do was a little too stretched to be a "eal world problem".

Maybe I will study more this "truncated normal distribution", but in my head the task was simpler than that... 
I'll try to write it differently. 

If I draw a gaussian and start to add the values, for example: I have 100 subjects, 10 did 48 points, the most frequent score, then 9 did 45 and other 9 did 52  and so on until I get 1 subject that did a low score and 1 that get a high score

Wouldn't be right?

Comment: There's nothing random about that process, making it very disconnected from any sort of real world example. Let's got back to the uniform distribution where the concepts are simpler...

Comment: Let's say you want scores uniformly distributed between 1 and 10. If you have 10 scores, you could put one each at 1, 2, 3, ..., 10. But that looks nothing like a real world example. To simulate a random process with that distribution you could do `sample(1:10, size = 10, replace = TRUE)`, and you will get random counts at each of the scores. But if you do that many times and average, you'll get each score ~10% of the time, using a process that has randomness in it.

Comment: Ok now i get it, i was trying to force it something that does not goes that way. Thanks for the explanation